# what to create PDF file in memory from bytes data type instead of using write binary python example

Tags: python, pdf

In following python code, I don't want use statement from # 6 to 8 but I want to create a PDF file from bytes data in memory and not on disk and display in the browser.

1. l_statement = "select srno,attachment from dbo.attachments where srno = 1"
2. sqlcursor.execute(l_statement)
3. for row in sqlcursor.fetchall():
4. ```
      print(type(row[1]))
   ```
5. ```
      print(row[1])
   ```
6. ```
      '''f='output.pdf'
   ```
7. ```
      with open(f,'wb') as outfile:
   ```
8. ```
           outfile.write(row[1])'''
   ```
9. webbrowser.open_new(pdf)

Output Datatype

<class 'bytes'>
b"%PDF-1.3\n1 0 obj\n<<\n/Count 1\n/Kids [3 0 R]\n/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]\n/Type /Pages\n>>\nendobj\n2 0 obj\n<<\n/OpenAction [3 0 R /FitH null]\n/PageLayout /OneColumn\n/Pages 1 0 R\n/Type /Catalog\n>>\nendobj\n3 0 obj\n<<\n/Contents 4 0 R\n/Parent 1 0 R\n/Resources 6 0 R\n/Type /Page\n>>\nendobj\n4 0 obj\n<<\n/Filter /FlateDecode\n/Length 74\n>>\nstream\nx\x9c3R\xf0\xe22\xd035W(\xe7r\nQ\xd0w3T04\xd330P\x08ISp\r\x01\t\x19\x1b\xea\x19Z(\x98\x9b\x99\xe9\x19\x19)\x84\xa4(hx\xa4\xe6\xe4\xe4+\x84\xe7\x17\xe5\xa4(j*\x84d\x81\xd4\x01\x00\x16#\x10M\nendstream\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<<\n/BaseFont /Helvetica-Bold\n/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding\n/Subtype /Type1\n/Type /Font\n>>\nendobj\n6 0 obj\n<<\n/Font <</F1 5 0 R>>\n/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC
/ImageI]\n>>\nendobj\n7 0 obj\n<<\n/CreationDate (D:20230929150353Z15'03')\n>>\nendobj\nxref\n0 8\n0000000000 65535 f \n0000000009 00000 n \n0000000096 00000 n \n0000000199 00000 n \n0000000279 00000 n \n0000000424 00000 n \n0000000526 00000 n \n0000000613 00000 n \ntrailer\n<<\n/Size 8\n/Root 2 0 R\n/Info 7 0 R\n/ID [<4527CC16A77C85F8369BA38DDA715212><4527CC16A77C85F8369BA38DDA715212>]\n>>\nstartxref\n674\n%%EOF\n"

Comment: `'''f='output.pdf'` should be `f= 'output.pdf'`

Comment: f='output.pdf'
   with open(f,'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(row[1])                                                                                                                         
These 3 lines are creating a file on local machine on c: drive which I don’t want, I want this file to be created in a memory and that I want to show in browser

Answer (score -1):

l_statement = "select srno,attachment from dbo.attachments where srno = 1"
print(l_statement)
sqlcursor.execute(l_statement)
for row in sqlcursor.fetchall():
headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="out.pdf"'}
return Response(row[1], headers=headers, media_type='application/pdf')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).